# Tailwind css remove opacity from custom color

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have added my custom color `titleColor` in `tailwind.config.js` .

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        titleColor: "hsl(0, 0%, 13%)",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

But on the browser its coming with the `opacity`. I do want exact color without any alteration.
[image]

How to remove opacity? Is it good practice to remove opacity? what will be effects if i remove it?  or any other way i can get my exact color without opacity?

Comment: Try using rgb value for `titleColor` in theme configuration

Answer (score 0):

That's the correct syntax for hsl(hsla):

```
hsla(H, S, L[, A])
```

A (alpha) can be a  between 0 and 1, or a , where the number 1 corresponds to 100% (full opacity).

So you should have something like:

```
hsla(0, 0%, 13%[, 0]);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/hsla doc here.